# static Class Design?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I wanted to know if this was good practice or not, I am not really sure if this class should be static class or not?

```
   public class SettingsHelper
{
    public static readonly string MinVal= "MinVal";
    public static readonly string MinPartners = "MinPartners";

    public static IDictionary<string, string> GetSettings(string jsonsettings)
    {
        var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonsettings);
        return settings;
    }


    public string SettingsToJson(IDictionary<string, string> settings)
    {
        var jsonsettings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
        return jsonsettings;
    }


    public static decimal GetMinPartners(string jsonsettings)
    {
        var settings = GetSettings(jsonsettings);

        string partners;
        settings.TryGetValue(MinPartners, out partners);

        return decimal.Parse(partners);
    }

    public static int GetMinValue(string jsonsettings)
    {
        var settings = GetSettings(jsonsettings);

        string pival;
        settings.TryGetValue(MinVal, out pival);

        return int.Parse(pival);
    }

}
```

I want to include methods such as, update partners, add partners etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that with 'static class' you mean a class with only static methods.

There are very few good reasons for static methods. Maybe if you need to implement a real Singleton (something that will try to kill you if it exists twice). But this doesn't seem to be the case here.

There are some acceptable reasons for static methods like

- there is no state
- alternative implementations really don't make much sense

These might apply in your case. => so the design might be ok.

Probably a proper class (or possibly a class per method) might be even better.

Clients of your methods/classes would get an instance in the constructor, possibly with a default constructor which creates the normal instances.

Here is what you would gain:

- When testing clients you can easily provide canned answers with mocks, you don't need to use valid json strings. In case of clients that don't create these Strings themselves this prevents tons of failures unrelated to the actual class under test when the structure of your json string changes.
- When some day some of this information comes from xml, a database or divination, especially when this distinction is made by client and not be type of information, it will be easy to switch.

Comment: could you provide a sample, rafactored code of mine to show me what is better design? I think I know what you are talking about but for the sake of clarity?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any benefit in having it static? It works just fine to instantiate it where ever it's needed.

I would name it `ConfigurationRepository` though. It describes the intent better. Also I would move  the serialization to a second class to keep the responsibilites clear.

Comment: I have not named it repository as it will not persist any data, this classes intent is to only help with getting data in the correct format so I can display

Comment: static- how about thread safety, or whatever, to be honest, I dont really know anything about that, so my concern was should I make it static so I dont store any state. It seems as though I should instantiate with the string as a param, then construct the data as needed?

Comment: Sorry, should the methods and class be a normal, non static class?

Comment: @Haroon, if you don't modify any state, you don't have to worry about thread-safety, whether you have an instance or a static class. But if you do and use an instance, you can just say that the class is not thread-safe and each thread should have its own instance. You can't do that with a static class, so designing static classes properly regarding this is usually harder.

Comment: @svick - could you clarify what you mean by modifying state? Is that from one web request to another, that needs to access the variable say Settings (which is a dictionary as in my example above)?

Comment: "Repository" doesnt imply that you MUST be able to store settings. imho "Helper" in class names usually means that you want to group similar functions together and not create a proper object oriented class.

Comment: @svick- so each thread will have its own instance of the class, so if the record is saved in the datbase, depending on when the new thread runs it can pick up the new data from the db?

Comment: @jgauffin - the way I have structured my code, it makes more sence not to be repo, but thanks for the heads up anyway, what you say does make sence...

Comment: State is something that the class remembers between method invocations. In your case, `settings` is not a state of `SettingsHelper`, because it always keeps reference to it only during one method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to avoid statics whenever possible. 
 - It makes your code less testable. You can not switch to a different version in your test cases. Again testing frameworks such as mockito do not support static well.

Static class makes sense if,

-all your methods are static
-you do not hold any global state in the class.
-you do not modify any of the member variables.
-all your functions are "helper" in nature.
-Your class is not creating a chain of other static classes.

As for Thread-safety, since your class is not modifying any global state (any member variable), it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

it need to be a static class, much less if all your functions in the class are static...
there is a data or behavior in the class that depends on object identity?